# jQuery Scrollify - content height bigger than section height generated by scrollify

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

I have integrated scrollify plugin. In many section, there is content bigger than the height generated by scrollify plugin. so whenever i have scrolled, some content not display. It should be scroll at end of content and then next section display as per scrollify plugins.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: maybe u should add ur code snippet here (or better if there is jsfiddle link)

Answer (score 0):

By default Scrollify will allow sections to expand beyond the page height and allow normal scrolling so that all content can be seen.
If this is not happening for you, you will need to adjust your settings.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into this.

Comment: I have the same issue. Should I do this with the $.scrollify.update() method? If so how can I do it?